# create swift module template like some popular module's file structure

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods

I'm trying to create my first swift module template. And I would like to create my file structure like some popular swift modules.

Such as:

- https://github.com/Quick/Quick
- https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire
- https://github.com/xmartlabs/Eureka

These modules have a similar file structure.

- Source
- Tests
- xxxx.xcworkspace
- xxx.xcodeproj
  ....

I've tried using `pod-template` and create by xcode `cocoa touch framework` but none of these are creating file structure above.

I thought it might be created by a template? Is it created by manual or is there a way I could create a template like them?

Comment: If you are starting I recommend you use `pod lib create`. Once you have more experience, modifying the structure of your pod should be easy. Here's more info about it https://guides.cocoapods.org/making/making-a-cocoapod.html

Comment: @EmilioPelaez thanks for the reply! I'm just curious are those project create by manual or by template?

Comment: If I had to guess I'd say they were structured manually by them